# In what order are theme files processed?

Tags: layout, magento2

Please note this question is about the yet-to-be-released [Magento 2](https://github.com/magento/magento2), which I'm still trying to get to grips with.

Each module contributes to each layout handle separately.  For example, the `default` handle is made up of these files:

```
app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/base/layout/default.xml

app/code/Magento/Bundle/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
app/code/Magento/Cms/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
app/code/Magento/Contact/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
app/code/Magento/Directory/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
app/code/Magento/GoogleAnalytics/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
app/code/Magento/Newsletter/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
app/code/Magento/PageCache/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
app/code/Magento/Reports/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
app/code/Magento/Rss/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
app/code/Magento/Sales/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
app/code/Magento/Weee/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
app/code/Magento/Widget/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
app/code/Magento/Wishlist/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
```

The `base` files come first followed by `frontend` files, followed by a number of themes.  I would like to know which order those in `frontend` are used.  I think `Magento/Theme/...` must be first because many others make references to it's blocks, be it adding, moving or removing.

I considered they might be following dependency order but that isn't adequate because there are many circular dependencies.  For example, `Magento_Customer` depends on `Magento_Theme` as you would expect, but `Magento_Theme` also depends on `Magento_Customer`.  If the wrong order is followed then important customer blocks would not be shown.

By setting breakpoints I've worked out the files are not loaded in any particular order, they are just dumped into a merged DOM to be dealt with later.  But I cannot tell what happens to the merged data afterwards, is it some kind of magic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modules are sorted based on their sequence dependencies.  The module with the least dependencies comes first, any module with a `<sequence>` dependency should be loaded after any of the modules declared in the *sequence* block.

[Module Sorting Logic](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/75b30dbc1ca0a41926784bd4d13fc889914aaa16/lib/Magento/Framework/Module/Declaration/Reader/Filesystem.php#L153)

[Layout File Sorting Decorator](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/75b30dbc1ca0a41926784bd4d13fc889914aaa16/lib/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/File/Source/Decorator/ModuleDependency.php#L79)

[Layout Merge Logic](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/75b30dbc1ca0a41926784bd4d13fc889914aaa16/app/code/Magento/Core/Model/Layout/Merge.php)

[Dependency Injection of Decorator](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/75b30dbc1ca0a41926784bd4d13fc889914aaa16/app/code/Magento/Core/etc/di.xml#L172)

Once the XML files are merged, there is more logic for how the different elements are processed.  First all the elements are read and updated, then all the moves are processed, and finally the removal of any blocks is processed.

[Logic for Processing Nodes](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/75b30dbc1ca0a41926784bd4d13fc889914aaa16/lib/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php#L320)

Comment: "is guaranteed" - unfortunately it is not guaranteed due to a few bugs, but yea, at least this is the idea! :-) Welcome to Magento Stackexchange!

Comment: Excellent use of source code. I was looking at some of those links specifically and noticed that `<depends>` and `<sequence>` are [treated equally](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/master/lib/Magento/Framework/Module/Declaration/Converter/Dom.php#L70).  That is, they are merged into the same `$moduleData['dependencies']` array so how are they distinguished?

Comment: Also, I accept this answer because it tells me what I needed to know.  My module(s) must declare it's dependencies appropriately for it's layouts to work.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt maybe "guaranteed" is too strong a word and I should edit my answer.  Still learning the rules of StackExchange.

Comment: @clockworkgeek I'm not sure that they are treated equally.  The nodes under `<sequence>` will be added to `$moduleData['dependencies']['modules']` while those under `<depends>` get added to `$moduleData['dependencies']['extensions']`.  Right now at least, the module dependencies are being used for the sort, not the extension dependencies.

Comment: Chris O'Toole your answer is great, don't get me wrong please :-) Just want to be sure, that if one is searching for a bug, one doesn't just exclude this. But most of the time it works.